# SUM OVER PARTITION BY in VIEW is NULL but works when used directly

Tags: sql-server

In a SQL Server 2016 database I have a table containing financial transactions:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions
    TxnId     int      NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    AccountId int      NOT NULL,
    DateTime  datetime NOT NULL,
    Amount    money    NOT NULL
)
```

I wrote a `VIEW` to display running balance information:

```
CREATE VIEW TransactionsWithBalance AS

SELECT
    *,
    SUM( Amount ) OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountId ORDER BY [DateTime], TxnId ) AS Balance
FROM
    Transactions
```

When I query this view, the `Balance` column contains all `NULL` values:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TransactionsWithBalance

TxnId    AccountId    DateTime      Amount    Balance
    1            1    2017-01-01    100.00    NULL
    2            1    2017-01-02    200.00    NULL
    3            2    2017-01-01     10.00    NULL
    4            1    2017-01-03    300.00    NULL
```

But when I run the query (with the `SUM( Amount ) OVER ( PARTITION BY... )`) query directly in SSMS I get the expected values in the `Balance` column.

```
TxnId    AccountId    DateTime      Amount    Balance
    1            1    2017-01-01    100.00     100.00
    2            1    2017-01-02    200.00     300.00
    3            2    2017-01-01     10.00      10.00
    4            1    2017-01-03    300.00     600.00
```

Why is the aggregate returning `NULL` values when queried inside a `VIEW`?

Comment: How weird, can't repro this. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=23083cb2219a247668b6c0e0e6b36387

Comment: @Lamak Interesting - this is weird then.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Do you have only 4 rows in the table? Can you also tell us the exact version? `select @@version;`

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in SQL fiddle or rextester. This is redundant, but what happens if you try building it as a derived table? `CREATE VIEW TransactionsWithBalance AS SELECT * FROM (SELECT
    *,
    SUM( Amount ) OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountId ORDER BY [DateTime], TxnId ) AS Balance
FROM
    Transactions t) t`

Comment: Again redundant, but alternatively creating it as a CTE: `create view TransactionsWithBalance as ;with t as (SELECT
    *,
    SUM( Amount ) OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountId ORDER BY [DateTime], TxnId ) AS Balance
FROM
    Transactions) select * from t`

Comment: @Simon I get a syntax error for the semi-colon for your second CTE example. The database compatibility level is 130.

Comment: @Simon The running balance is displayed when I query your first CTE VIEW example. The plot thickens!

Comment: @Dai that is because Simon has confused the semi-colon. He is using it as a statement "beginninator" instead of a statement terminator, which is somewhat common because lots of people start their cte with a semicolon because it requires that the previous statement be terminated with a semicolon. Remove that and your view will be created.

Comment: Sorry about that Dai, and thank you @SeanLange for catching that. :-)

Comment: I can only reproduce it [like this](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2c761d6df5e03c38cb5d3befb6d5251b) (CC @Lamak).

Comment: @AndriyM interesting.

Comment: @AndriyM That's *weird* - but it might be my problem,as I know I've added and removed columns in the table since I created the `VIEW`. I'm not able to access the DB right now but I'll try recreating the view and seeing what happens. Good find though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the things that can happen when metadata gets out of sync because you didn't either:

- Schema bind the view; or
- Call [`sp_refreshview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshview-transact-sql) whenever an object underlying the view changes

  > #### Remarks
  >
  > If a view is not created with schemabinding, **sp_refreshview** should be run when changes are made to the objects underlying the view that affect the definition of the view. Otherwise, the view might produce unexpected results when it is queried.

The better option would probably be to use schema binding. This will also force you to not use `SELECT *` in the view, and use a two-part name for the table, both best practices:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.TransactionsWithBalance
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    TRN.TxnId, 
    TRN.AccountId,
    TRN.[DateTime],
    TRN.Amount,
    Balance =
        SUM(TRN.Amount) OVER (
            PARTITION BY TRN.AccountId 
            ORDER BY TRN.[DateTime], TRN.TxnId)
FROM
    dbo.Transactions AS TRN;
```

Comment: This fixed it. Use SSMS to `DROP + CREATE` the view and querying from it again now works. I thought that VIEWs were composable though and would generate a new execution plan when used in a different query (like UDFs) so to read that VIEWs can be broken so easily is somewhat unnerving.